# Audio tag auto play not working in android browser

Tags: html, audio, createjs

I created an audio player dynamically with autoplay enabled. But it is working with desktop browser not in android browser. And `progress` handler not dispatched.

If I enable the `controls` attribute and click the play button it will dispatch the progress handler and playing the audio. Even I was tried to play by manually by calling the `play()` method.

I want to play the audio once `canplaythrough` handler triggered.

Answer (score 2):

Audio on mobile devices often requires a user event (click / touch) in order to play, which seems to be what is happening in your case.

You can check out the SoundJS [Mobile Safe Tutorial](http://www.createjs.com/tutorials/Mobile%20Safe%20Approach/) to learn more about the issue and a couple of ways to work around it.

Hope that helps.